# Combining JavaScript Arrays Dynamically

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a JavaScript function to combine arrays. I'd like to be able to accept a variable number of arrays as arguments passed into the function, but I can't seem to get it to work. I tried the following:

```
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
        var retArray = [];
        args.forEach(function(a) {
            return retArray.concat(a);
        });
        return retArray;
```

But with no success. Am I missing something?

Comment: What do you mean "no success"? What isn't working? What do you see vs what do you expect to see?

Comment: (BTW, `concat` already accepts a list of arrays to merge.)

Comment: Huh. If concat already does it, there's not much point to this question. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.

```
function foo() {
    var combinedArr = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], arguments);
    console.log(combinedArr);
}

foo([1, 2], [4, 3, 5], [6, 7, 8]);
```